# Ошибка при создании Activity с Fragment'ом, имеющим <layout/>

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, android-layout

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть Activity, в которой находится . Есть Fragment, имеющий элемент . При запуске выдаёт такую ошибку: "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class layout"

Ниже показаны соответственно MainActivity с разметкой и MainFragment с разметкой.

MainActivity.java:

```
package ru.quzox.fragmentviewmodeltest1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import ru.quzox.fragmentviewmodeltest1.ui.main.MainFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    }
}
```

main_activty.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <fragment
            class="ru.quzox.fragmentviewmodeltest1.ui.main.MainFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/main_fragment"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

MainFragment.java:

```
package ru.quzox.fragmentviewmodeltest1.ui.main;

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import ru.quzox.fragmentviewmodeltest1.R;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private MainViewModel mViewModel;

    public static MainFragment newInstance() {
        return new MainFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
        // TODO: Use the ViewModel
    }

}
```

main_fragment.java:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</layout>
```

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Код надо текстом, не скриншотами. С них ничего не скопировать и они не индексируются поисковиками. По сути вопроса - у вас layout тэг пустой. Добавьте в него что-то. Например FrameLayout

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо, скриншоты заменил на текст. Насчёт заполнения тэга layout - добавил FrameLayout, но ошибка остаётся та же.

Comment: Покажите лог ошибки целиком - возможно там указано в чём именно дело.

Comment: Если вы хотите использовать `Data Binding Library` - то почитайте обучающие материалы для начала. Обычный инфлейтер не знает что делать с этим тегом. Нужно использовать [`DataBindingUtil`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil). Примерно так должно быть во фрагменте: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34719627

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо большое, всё работает!

Comment: @woesss, по идее ваш комментарий можно в ответ поместить)

Comment: @woesss, Спасибо!